# How to correctly SEO positioning of articles that require authorization

Tags: seo, google-search, search-engines, authentication

I have website with lot of articles, but that require sign-in to view it. The titles of articles are public.

When user is not logged in but wants to see and read it, then will be redirected to login page.

The question is: How to correctly SEO positioning of articles that require authorization? I would like to see article titles in results in search engines.

Answer (score 1):

> Check [Google's official guide for paywalled content](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/paywalled-content).

In order to give you some more ideas, you can establish a login system based on cookies. You should restrict access based on two premises:

1. **There is not a cookie present**, therefore the user is not logged and can't read the article.
2. **It's not Googlebot** as bots will always have access to the articles in order to crawl them. Check [how to verify GoogleBot](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/80553?hl=en) in order to never prevent it to crawl and take a look at Medium as they have a similar subscription plan as the one you want to implement.

In order to prevent [cloaking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloaking) and [being aligned with Google Guidelines](https://kloos.agency/blog/paywalls-and-seo/), there are two possibilities:

- **Metering**: provides users with a quota of free articles to consume, before they have to pay for more. This could be 5 per day or 3 per month – the amount is up to each publisher.
- **Lead-in**: offers a portion of the article’s content, while not showing the entire article. To read the full article, the user has to pay. For that, you must use [`NewsArticle` structured data](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/article) to specify which content is not free.